# subfunction/class manipulation of built-in functions in python

Tags: python, stdin, prompt, sys

for my masterthesis i am working with the vmtk and vtk package.
Currently i am trying to figure out how to prompt the user for a string input within a vtkRenderWindow.
Unfortunately, there is no built-in method in vtk nor any practical code example on how to achieve this.
Fortunately -more or less- the vmtk package offers such a function.
As this will end up as a more basic question than it seems now, i dont think it is required to know the vmtk package at all to relate to my question.

So the source code for the function of the respective functionality in vmtk looks like this:

```
def InputText(self,prompt='',validator=None):
    self.OutputText(prompt)
    try:
        self.InputStream.prompt(prompt)
    except:
        pass
    text = self.InputStream.readline()
    if text:
        text = text.rstrip('\n')
    if validator:
        while not validator(text):
            self.OutputText(prompt)
            try:
                self.InputStream.prompt(prompt,info=False)
            except:
                pass
            text = self.InputStream.readline()
            if text:
                text = text.rstrip('\n')
    return text
```

The validator is a side-function for checking the input and doesnt interest us and this point.
self.InputStream is defined in **init** as: self.InputStream = sys.stdin

At this point it gets frustrating, at least for me. And let me say that i am no experienced programmer at all, intermediate at most.

To readline and strip part seems logical to me. It basically read in the string/word that was typed into the InputStream and strips the newline-character.

My problem is the prompt "subfunction" that is called. That attribute does no exist for sys.stdin...
And i am pretty sure that this is exactly the functionality that i am looking for.

So is there a way to redefine basic functionalities in python?
Because if this attribute does not exist in the buil-in sys package it must have been added or redefined somewhere in the script or imported scripts (and i can't find it).

Comment: This code does not require that the `.prompt()` method exists; the `try`/`except` around the calls to it mean that the lack of this method will be silently ignored.  `self.OutputText(prompt)` is what produces the prompt in such cases (such as using standard IO channels).  If `InputStream` was changed to be something like a dialog box in a GUI, then it could implement `.prompt()` in order to fill in the content of that dialog box.

Comment: But the OutputStream does only show the query string, it does not read in the input form the user does it? Also, what you said last is exactly what is happening, this "prompting" takes places within a explicit window. Edit: I found the functionality, thanks for the lead!

Comment: There may not be any definitions of `.prompt()` supplied with this package.  It's just a hook for users of the package to provide a more suitable implementation of user input than a write to `OutputText` followed by a read from `InputStream`.